# beginners program designed using threads and classes

Tags: python, multithreading, class

It seems that this question is too long for anyone to comment on... I'm trying to print out some text and a progress bar in a module called 'laulau.py'. Here's a test piece of code that shows a simple version. My goal is to have only *one* thread, and send information to it. My question is ***what is the best way to do this ?***

file1 (test.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from laulau import laulau
import time

print "FIRST WAY"

total=107
t=laulau()
t.echo('this is text')
t.setbartotal(total)
for a in range(1,total):
    t.updatebar(a)
    time.sleep(0.01)
time.sleep(1)
print
print "\ndone loop\n"
t.stop()
time.sleep(1)

print "SECOND WAY"

with laulau().echo("this is text"):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "\nyes this is working\n"
    time.sleep(2)
```

file2: laulau.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim:fileencoding=utf8

from __future__ import division
import time
import string
import threading
from sys import stdout


class laulau(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        super(laulau,self).__init__()
        self._stop = False
        self.block='█'
        self.empty='□'
        self.TEMPLATE = ('%(progress)s%(empty)s %(percent)3s%%')
        self.progress = None
        self.percent = 0
        self.bar_width=30
        self.bartotal=None

    def run (self):
        # start thread for text
        while not self._stop:
            if self.bartotal is None:
                print self.arg,
                stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            else:
                self.progress = int((self.bar_width * self.percent) / 100)
                self.data = self.TEMPLATE % {
                        'percent': self.percent,
                        'progress': self.block * self.progress,
                        'empty': self.empty * (self.bar_width - self.progress),
                }

                stdout.write('\033[%dG'%1 + self.data + self.arg)
                stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def setbartotal(self,total):
        # set progress bar total
        if self.bartotal is None:
            self.bartotal = total
            self.updatebar(0)

    def updatebar (self,num):
        self.num=num
        self.percent = self.percentage(self.num)

    def percentage (self,numagain):
        return int((numagain/self.bartotal)*100+1)

    def echo (self,arg="Default"):
        #self.thread_debug()
        self.arg=arg
        self._stop = False
        self.start()
        return self

    def thread_debug(self):
        print "threading enumerate :%s"%threading.enumerate()
        print "current thread :%s"%threading.currentThread()
        print "thread count (including main thread):%s"%threading.activeCount() 

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop == True

    def __enter__(self):
        print "\nwe have come through the enter function\n"
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._stop = True
        print "\nwe have exited through the exit function\n"
        return isinstance(value, TypeError)
```

In some cases the second way could work. e.g., when I am printing some text, and just need the thread to die at the end of it, but not in the case of a progress bar when it needs updates sending to it. While this all sort of works, and I learned a lot, I still can't figure out how to encapsulate this class in the way I want. As I only want one thread I don't really need to keep instantiating the class, I just need to do this once.

so e.g. my ideal way would be having three functions only:

- 1 to control text, turn on progress bar etc (from within one parsed string)
- 2 to set the progress bar total
- 3 to set the progress bar iteration

I need to change two variables in the class (for the progress bar)

- one for the total
- one for the iteration

...and it works out percentage from that.

First I thought I should start the thread by inheriting the class stuff from threading, then after looking at `threading.Thread(target=blah,etc)` at first I couldn't see how to use more than one function, then I discovered I could just put the class name in there `threading.Thread(target=laulau)` and that would start a thread with the class in, but then I was stumped on how to send that thread information seeing as I hadn't assigned it to a 'name' as in `t=laulau()`

My second thought was to have functions outside of the class in my module, but because I need more than one function I got a bit confused there too by adding this to the beginning of laulau.py:

```
def eko (arg):
    t=laulau()  
    t.echo(arg)

def barupate(iteration):
    t.updatebar(a)

def bartotal():
    t.setbartotal(a)
```

the first function made an instance of the class but the preceding functions could not change any variables within that. and *then* i came across function attributes such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses).

```
class Foo:
    @webmethod
    def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
         ...

def webmethod(func):
    func.is_webmethod = True
    return func
```

I then started thinking maybe I could use this somehow but have never come across it before.

Ideally id like something like this:

```
echo.total(107)
echo('[progressbar] this is text') # starts progress bar and instance of thread if not already there...
for a in range(1,total):
    echo.updatebar(a)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    time.sleep(1)
    echo.stop() # bar would stop at the end of iterations but text animations (blinking etc) may still be going at this point...
    print
    print "\ndone loop\n"
```

if you know about python you are probably looking at me funny now, but bear in mind that I'm a total beginner non-professional and am learning every day, a lot of it thanks to this site. cheers for any help!

edit: should add that I'm aware of the progress bar module and various other recipes, but I'm making this for learning and fun purposes :)

Comment: Do you really need to implement your own progress bar module? In any case, it's worth looking at [`python-progressbar`](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/).

Comment: yeah seen that, have to pick it apart a bit... they cant spell 'tipically' :) its not just a progress bar module, it also prints text. i like the way they call it there `pbar =ProgressBar(widgets=widgets) for i in pbar((i for i in range(24))):`

Comment: You're right, this is too long :) but that said, I don't understand why you're using threading to update and display a progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to print out a progress bar, use the sys module, like so:

```
import sys
import time

progress = "0"                                 #this is an int meant to represent 0-100 percent as 0-100
old = "0"                                      #this represents the last updates progress, so that this update only adds the difference and not the full progress

def updatebar(progress,old):
    for item in range((progress-old)/2)        #this takes the range of progress but divides it by 2, making the progress bar 50 characters long
    sys.stdout.write("-")                      #to change the character used to fill the progress bar change the "-" to something else
    sys.stdout.flush()

#you may not want to use a while loop here, this just has an example of how to use the update function as it adds one to the progress bar every second
while True:
    progress += 1
    updatebar(progress,old)
    old = progress                             #sets the old progress as the current one, because next iteration of the while loop the previous progress will be this one's current progress.
    time.sleep(1)
```