# Can I assign attribute to a function inside itself?

Tags: python

Today I found that I can assign attribute to function, but when I tried to assign the attribute inside itself, I failed:

```
>>> def a():
...     pass
...
>>> a.x = 1
>>> a.x
1
>>> def b():
...     b.x = 2
...
>>> b.x
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Is there a way to assign attribute to a function inside himself?

If there isn't, what's the usage of a function's attribute?

Comment: "I failed:" Yes, for the same reason that, if the code inside `b()` said `print("hello")`, the code would not print `hello`. The code inside the function only runs when the function is called. `b.x = 2` is code inside the function. The function is not called, therefore the code does not run. This is elementary logical reasoning that has **nothing to do with** function attributes being special (they aren't particularly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a function is not evaluated until the function is actually called; `b.x` in your example does not exist until `b` has been called at least once.

One use is to simulate C-style static variables, whose values persist between calls to the function. A trivial example counts how many times the function has been called.

```
def f():
    f.count += 1
    print "Call number {0}".format(count)
f.count = 0
```

Note that there is no problem assigning to `f.count` from inside `count`, but the initial assignment must occur after `f` is defined, since `f` does not exist until then.

Comment: What's the usage of function attribute?

Comment: I think there is an exception, I can assign __doc__ attribute inside a function itself, and can get it just like in the 'b.x' way I've mentioned above.

Comment: The difference is that `__doc__` (along with some other attributes) is predefined by the `def` statement itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [pep-0232](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/). And this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses)