# python: variables in a function with dot preceded by the function name

Tags: python-3.x, function

I need to understand this concept wherein we can use the dot (.) in the variable name within a function definition. There's no class definition nor a module here and Python is not supposed accept a variable name that includes a dot.

```
def f(x):
    f.author = 'sunder'
    f.language = 'Python'
    print(x,f.author,f.language)

f(5)
`>>> 5 sunder Python`
```

Please explain how this is possible, and suggest related documentation for further exploration.

Comment: You are missing some code. `f` must have been defined earlier.

Comment: definitely not. These are the first lines I typed.

Comment: Well, I can't replicate. I get, predictably: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'`.

Comment: What makes you think that the dot syntax can only be used on classes and modules?

Comment: @jpp apologies. edited the code part. replaced 'name' with 'author'

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Python function attributes - uses and abuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses)

Comment: @Aran-Fey can you please elaborate on other cases where dot is used? Where and how to use. If not, just provide a link/book I can refer to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `foo.bar` to get the `bar` attribute of `foo`. It doesn't matter what `foo` is. It doesn't have to be a class or a module. It can be used on anything that has attributes.

Comment: @jpp, thanks for the link to the 'function attributes' thread. It was useful. I didn't know these are also called function attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> Programmer’s note: Functions are first-class objects. A “def” statement executed inside a function definition defines a local function that can be returned or passed around. Free variables used in the nested function can access the local variables of the function containing the def.

So, function is an object:

```
>>> f.__class__
<class 'function'>
>>> f.__class__.__mro__
(<class 'function'>, <class 'object'>)
```

... and it means that it can store attributes:

```
>>> f.__dict__
{'language': 'Python', 'author': 'sunder'}
 >>> dir(f)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'author', 'language']
```