# numpy vs. python: patch the round function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file, which defines

```
def foo(x):
   return round(x)
```

Here `round` is the python `built-in` function.

Now, I would like to call this function with a numpy array. Numpy has a `round` function, too. Unfortunately, there are issues (e.g. [#11557](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11557))

```
import numpy as np

foo(7.6)
foo(np.array([7.6]))       # works with python2 + np_1.14.0, not with 3.6.9 + np_1.14.5
foo(np.array([7.6, 8.9]))  # TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

Are there possibilities to replace the function `round` with `np.round` inside the `foo` function? Some patch like `round = np.round` before import or `foo.round = np.round` after import?

Edit:
I'm looking for a solution without modifing the file.

Comment: You can use `np.round` instead. Note that `numpy` rounding behavior may differ from that of Python's builtin `round`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can do it. Just check class of the x using isinstance

```
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        return x.round()
    return round(x)


print(foo(7.6))
print(foo(np.array([7.6])))
print(foo(np.array([7.6, 8.9])))
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without modifing the file. I clarified this now.

Comment: in this case I think you need to monkey patch module or create your own class derived from numpy.ndarray with supporting roung.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass is a work around (as @Anton Pomieshchenko commented)

```
class Array(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, array, **kwargs):
        return np.asarray(array, **kwargs).view(cls)
    def __round__(self):
        return np.round(self.data)

foo(Array([7.6, 8.9]))
```

Works for python 3, while in python 2 I get `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

I without success I tried also `np.__round__ = np.round` (TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars) or `np.ndarray.__round__ = np.round` (TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'numpy.ndarray').

Answer (score 0):

This requires to modify the file, but the file remains independent of numpy.
The modified file `bar.py` is

```
def foo(x):
   return foo.round(x)

foo.round = round
```

Then the `round` function can be replaced after import

```py
from bar import foo
import numpy as np
foo(7.6)
foo.round = np.round
foo([7.6, 8.9])       #
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/338420/11769765.

Alternatively, using

```
from builtins import round

def foo(x):
   return round(x)
```

for `bar.py`, makes the round method accessbile

```
from bar import foo
import bar
import numpy as np
foo(7.6)           # 8
bar.round = np.round
foo([7.6, 8.9])    # array([8., 9.])
```