# How to set a repr for a function itself?

Tags: python, repr

`__repr__` is used to return a string representation of an object, but in Python a function is also an object itself, and [can have attributes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/).

How do I set the `__repr__` of a function?

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses) that an attribute can be set for a function outside the function, but typically one sets a `__repr__` within the object definition itself, so I'd like to set the repr within the function definition itself.

---

My use case is that I am using [tenacity](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to retry a networking function with exponential backoff, and I want to log the (informative) name of the function I have called last.

```
retry_mysql_exception_types = (InterfaceError, OperationalError, TimeoutError, ConnectionResetError)


def return_last_retry_outcome(retry_state):
    """return the result of the last call attempt"""
    return retry_state.outcome.result()


def my_before_sleep(retry_state):
    print("Retrying {}: attempt {} ended with: {}\n".format(retry_state.fn, retry_state.attempt_number, retry_state.outcome))


@tenacity.retry(wait=tenacity.wait_random_exponential(multiplier=1, max=1200),
                stop=tenacity.stop_after_attempt(30),
                retry=tenacity.retry_if_exception_type(retry_mysql_exception_types),
                retry_error_callback=return_last_retry_outcome,
                before_sleep=my_before_sleep)
def connect_with_retries(my_database_config):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**my_database_config)
    return connection
```

Currently `retry_state.fn` displays something like `<function <lambda> at 0x1100f6ee0>` like @chepner says, but I'd like to add more information to it.

Comment: You can print the function's name by using func.__name__

Comment: I think a class with a `__call__` method would be more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: @Georgy it seems I missed that in my initial search and my question is indeed a duplicate question, however the answers here are so much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a custom decorator could help:

```
import functools


class reprable:
    """Decorates a function with a repr method.

    Example:
        >>> @reprable
        ... def foo():
        ...     '''Does something cool.'''
        ...     return 4
        ...
        >>> foo()
        4
        >>> foo.__name__
        'foo'
        >>> foo.__doc__
        'Does something cool.'
        >>> repr(foo)
        'foo: Does something cool.'
        >>> type(foo)
        <class '__main__.reprable'>
    """

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped
        functools.update_wrapper(self, wrapped)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self._wrapped.__name__}: {self._wrapped.__doc__}'
```

Demo: http://tpcg.io/uTbSDepz.

Comment: This is basically the same as [Hielke's older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597640/364696) (just without the ability to customize the `repr` on a per-function basis).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah, I wrote my answer too slow... :(

Comment: I like the `update_wrapper` addition.

Comment: `self._wrapped` is redundant because [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) automatically adds a `__wrapped__` attribute to the wrapper.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a decorator that returns a class with the `__call__` and `__repr__` set:

```
class CustomReprFunc:

    def __init__(self, f, custom_repr):
        self.f = f
        self.custom_repr = custom_repr

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.custom_repr(self.f)


def set_repr(custom_repr):
    def set_repr_decorator(f):
        return CustomReprFunc(f, custom_repr)
    return set_repr_decorator


@set_repr(lambda f: f.__name__)
def func(a):
    return a


print(repr(func))
```

Comment: Ah you beat me by a few seconds! It might be worth highlighting that you're not actually adding `__repr__` to a function, but rather to a class that wraps the function.

Comment: Note: This does make the function calls slower. In reality, I'd probably just adjust the point where you're printing it to produce a more friendly string, without changing or wrapping the function.

Comment: @flakes Yes correct, the decorator now return a class. So it now an instance of `CustomReprFunc `.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, you can play with CustomReprFunc and also e.g. make a decorator that by default sends `__name__` or just a string. Can save quite a bit of function calls, and you have to remember that function calls in Python are quite slow.

Comment: I'd suggest also using [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) to make the class behave more like the actual function (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

It's already set.

```
>>> repr(lambda x:x)
'<function <lambda> at 0x1100f6ee0>'
```

The problem is that the `function` type is immutable, so you can't just assign a new function to `function.__repr__`, and you also can't create a subtype of `function` in order to override `__repr__`. (Not that creating instances of the subclass would be easy, even if it were possible to define it.)

Comment: Weirdly enough, trying to override `.__repr__` doesn't seem to produce an error, although it does not affect the result of `repr()`: `def f(x): return 2*x    f.__repr__=lambda:'x -> 2x'    repr(f)    f.__repr__()` in the python repl shows me `'<function f at 0x102a8d048>'` for `repr(f)` and `'x -> 2x'` for `f.__repr__()`.

Comment: @Stef: `__repr__`, like most special methods, is, partially for performance reasons, looked up on the type, not the instance. So reassigning it on a specific function doesn't do anything (and you can't reassign it on the `function` type).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this for actual functions; the `function` type is immutable, and already defines a `__repr__`, and `__repr__` is looked up on the type, not the instance, so changing `__repr__` on a given function doesn't change behavior.

While probably not useful in this case, you *can* make your own callable class (analogous to C++ functors), and those *can* define their own `__repr__`. For example:

```
class myfunction:
    @staticmethod   # Avoids need to receive unused self
    def __call__(your, args, here):
        ... do stuff and return as if it were a function ...

    @classmethod    # Know about class, but again, instance is useless
    def __repr__(cls):
        return f'{cls.__name__}(a, b, c)'
```

which you could convert to a singleton instance of the class (making it equivalent to a plain function in how you use it) at the end by just doing:

```
myfunction = myfunction()
```

to replace the class with a single instance of the class.

Note: In real code, I'd almost certainly just change where I'm printing it to print in a more useful way without modifying the function. This doesn't have *much* overhead over a plain function or a wrapped plain function (since we put the function itself in `__call__` rather than wrapping, making it faster, but requiring a separate class for each "friendly `repr` function"), but it's just not the job of the function to decide how to represent itself in a human-friendly way; that's your job, based on the situation.

Comment: I think I prefer Hielke's answer a little bit more, because as a wrapper, the pattern can be repeated more easily. Btw, I've never tried this. Does adding `__call__` as a class method effectively make the class non-instantiable by masking `__init__`?

Comment: @flakes: No. `__call__` is invoked when you "call" the instances (that's why you'd do `myfunction = myfunction()` to replace it with an instance of the class). So putting parentheses after the class name invokes `__init__` (after `__new__` if that's defined). Putting them after an instance of the class invokes `__call__`. Fun trivia: If you have a metaclass that defines `__call__`, the metaclass's `__call__` will be invoked before `__new__`/`__init__` because you're calling an instance of the metaclass (the class itself).

Comment: @flakes: I agree that Hielke's answer is more flexible. But I also think that it's putting responsibility in the wrong place; if you want a friendly string version of a function, write a single bit of code that does the conversion where you need it, don't make people wrap their functions all over the code base to make them work well with your single consumer.

Comment: I generally agree with you, but it's a relatively low cost when considering tenacity is already being wrapped around the method.

Comment: Also agree that this is more of an x/y problem than anything else. I feel it's more of a "how far can I bend this language?" type question.

Answer (score 3):

You can change `retry_state.fn` to `retry_state.__name__`. I use many decorators like this. If you add a decorator, it will be called each time a function of interest is called.

```
def display_function(func):
    """ This decorator prints before and after running """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'\nNow: Calling {func.__name__}.')
        entity = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'Done: Calling {func.__name__}.\n')
        return entity

    return function_wrapper
```

---

Additionally, the retrying module in python allows you to do some of what you're doing by default. I often use a decorator:

```
import retrying
@retrying.retry(wait_exponential_multiplier=1000, wait_exponential_max=10000)
```