# Retaining a variable value over different method calls

Tags: python

I call a method (which is imported from a separate file) multiple times. This method contains a variable whose value I would like to retain between all the times I call the method (without returning it and having it as an argument). For example, I would like to compute a mean of all the values computed across different calls to that function. Is it possible (for example, by making it global or in any other way)?

In `file1.py` I make the following import

```
from file2 import my_method

my_method()
```

`file2.py` contains `my_method`

```
def my_method():
    #some computation involving variable `a`
    return  # a is not returned
```

We would like to retain `a` across different calls. The only thing that comes to my mind now is to save the variable `a` and read it back every time I call the method.

Note: I can edit `file1.py` and `file2.py` but I cannot modify the arguments nor the return values of `my_method`

Comment: If you want to carry state between function calls, you need to use a global variable or make the function a method of a class whose instances store the state. You'll need to be more precise about what you are trying to do (preferably by providing a minimal code example we could run).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)

Comment: @chepner those arent the only ways - there are also function and method attributes. However if by ‘method’ you mean this of a class, then use an instance attribute of course. But for standalone function then yes function attributes would be a reasonable way to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses also see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/

Comment: I don't consider either to be a good idea.

Comment: Globals are definitely not a good idea. Instance attributes certainly seem the most sensible route.

Comment: @chepner A global is almost certainly not the correct solution here. Perhaps creating a class with a field is, but that should be driven by the problem domain, not trying to find the solution domain. Another alternative is to pass the value in as a parameter. But again, whether or not this is a good solution is determined by the problem being solved.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to revisit the design of your functions. When you have a local variable's value that needs to be retained, then that variable shouldn't be local. Instead, it should be passed into the function as a parameter or possibly stored as a class field.

There are many different ways to solve your problem, but it all comes down to design. We will need more details to give specific suggestions.